# Can skype-metro run in the background

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app, skype-metro

I'm having an issue when trying to use the modern-UI Skype app in parallel to other apps (notably full-screen games):

Whenever I switch to another app (e.g. the desktop) while I'm in a call on Skype, the call gets suspended. When using another modern-UI app or traditional desktop app, I can split the screen and have the Skype app running in a sidebar to prevent the suspending of the call. When I launch a full-screen game on the desktop however, this workaround does not help. Is there any way to get modern-UI Skype to run in the background like the traditional desktop based application so that I can continue calling while I'm in a game?

Comment: Unless you close a Modern UI application by dragging the application to the bottom of the screen it will continue to operate in the background.  In this specific case the call is place on hold because your settings are configured to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound Is it possible that there's a setting somewhere? Because I haven't been able to keep a call on Skype while running Civilization 5. Once I start the game, I cannot hear the other end any more.

Comment: The setting to allow Skype to run in the background can be controlled in `PC Setting`

Comment: @Ramhound Would you please give me some guidance on how to reach that setting?

Comment: I would uninstall and reinstall the application.  When you do this you will get a prompt if you want to allow the application to run in the background.  It appears you have to make the Skype tile a "Live tile" you do this by right clicking on it.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried removing and reinstalling the app, but I did not get a prompt about running in the background, just for using the camera and microphone. And it still mutes when I switch to another app.

Comment: Did you try right clicking the tile?

Comment: @Ramhound I did, and only got the option to "Turn live tile off"

Comment: That means it already set to run in the background but designed to place the call on hold.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, that was my question - is it designed to always put the call on hold, or is there any way to get it to keep the call going? And is it an OS limitation, or a limitation of Skype?